# Why some web sites uses multiple fonts inside their CSS file such as ((font: bold 12px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;))

Tags: css

I used the firebug tool to check the font family that is used insdie a web application, and the firebug display the following :-

```
font: bold 12px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

So why this web application uses multiple font families instead of only one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows for fallback fonts if a font is not available on a user's system. If Verdana is not available the browser will then try to use Arial. If Arial is not available it will try to use Helvetica, etc. Typically, custom fonts are listed first and then get more generic as the list progress with the last font listed usually being a system default available on all operating systems.